# Как с помощью css сделать перенос строк и добавление 3 точек в конце

Tags: html, css

Как с помощью Сss сделать перенос строк на три строки и добавление 3 точек в конце как тут
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а количество символов в превью к статье известно ?

Comment: да допустим 100, это не столь важно, важна сама суть возможно ли это реализовать на css?

Comment: это вариант ? https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/jdwewa

Comment: это очень хорошо! а можно ли как то ограничить текст чтобы он был не более чем в 3 строки? остальной текст обрезался бы под троеточием. Просто туда летят динамические данные и я не могу знать сколько там символов будет. Или это только все на js?

Comment: нет ...в моём случае блок обрезает текст

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как добавить многоточие после последнего слова в многострочном тексте?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/600204/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bc%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d0%bc%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d1%87%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b5)