# Как обрезать тест?

Tags: html, css

тоесть если больше двух строк - добавляем ...

```css
.wrap {
  display: flex;
}

.item {
  width: 50%;
  outline: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="item">
    <p>лыжи лыжи лыжи лыжи лыжи лыжилыжи лыжи лыжилыжи лыжи лыжилыжи лыжи лыжи Черная с красным еще gggggggg gggggg gggggggggg fff...</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <p>лыжи лыжи лыжилыжи лыжи лыжилыжи лыжи лыжилыжи лыжи лыжилыжи лыжи лыжилыжи лыжи лыжилыжи лыжи лыжилыжи лыжи лыжилыжи лыжи лыжилыжи лыжи лыжилыжи лыжи лыжилыжи лыжи лыжиtexttext text fff...</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/600204/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3922739/limit-text-length-to-n-lines-using-css